# Working with Rails nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I started working with nested resources. I have been reading this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources so I created 2 models, a product and a senders. Product has many Senders. My Sender model is this:

```
class Sender < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :email, :name

  belongs_to :product
end
```

My product is this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price

   #Relationships !
   has_many :senders,  dependent: :destroy
end
```

in my routes.rb:

```
  resources :products do
     resources :senders
  end
```

now rake routes gives me all the right routes it should, according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

So when I type in the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/products/1/senders/new
```

so I create a new sender for my product with id = 1 I get this:

```
 NoMethodError in Senders#new

undefined method `senders_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003fcf9d8>:0x00000003e6f408>
```

Why do I get this undefined method since it should give me the new.html.erb page for the sender of that product??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if you did `rake routes`, you would not find the route you are looking for. This is because your routes for `senders` are nested within `products`.

Therefore, if you want to create a new sender, the path should be something like `new_product_sender_path(product)`.

So, to get all the senders of a particular product, the path would be `product_senders_path(product)`.