# Rails: can't work out the parameters for linked resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have models `Project` and `Model`. A `Project` has many `models` and a `Model` belongs to a `project`. In my routing, I have:

```
shallow do
  resources :projects do
    resources :models
  end
end
```

In `projects.show.html.erb` I have `<%= link_to 'New Model', new_project_model_path %>`, which fails with `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"models", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:project_id]`.

I suppose that's fair enough because I've not told it what project the new model will belong to, but I can't work out how to tell it.

I've tried changing the `link_to` to read `<%= link_to 'New Model', new_project_model_path(@project) %>` based on the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120907/working-with-rails-nested-resources), but that breaks the default `models/_form.html.erb` that the scaffold set up: the opening line, `<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>` fails with `undefined method 'models_path' for #<#<Class:0x5b868e8>:0x5c56518>`. I don't remember saying anything about `model_path`!

Can somebody tell this Ruby Newbie how to do it? (And to make me extra happy, point me to where I should have found it in the documentation? I keep reading [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), but although it shows me how to set up the nesting, I can't see how to *use* the nesting.)

Edit: The relevant bit of the `rake routes` output is:

```
        project_models GET    /projects/:project_id/models(.:format)             models#index
                       POST   /projects/:project_id/models(.:format)             models#create
     new_project_model GET    /projects/:project_id/models/new(.:format)         models#new
            edit_model GET    /models/:id/edit(.:format)                         models#edit
                 model GET    /models/:id(.:format)                              models#show
                       PATCH  /models/:id(.:format)                              models#update
                       PUT    /models/:id(.:format)                              models#update
                       DELETE /models/:id(.:format)                              models#destroy
              projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                projects#index
                       POST   /projects(.:format)                                projects#create
           new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                            projects#new
          edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                       projects#edit
               project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                            projects#show
                       PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                            projects#update
                       PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                            projects#update
                       DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                            projects#destroy
```

Comment: Remove `shallow: true` from your route.

Comment: That doesn't help - I still can't work out the correct invocation to get to the new model form (or to the show model page). And anyway, isn't shallow routing best practice?

Comment: Can you please post the outcome or `rake routes`. Run that command in the terminal and post the output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new_project_model_path(@project)` is the correct form.

That will call `new` in the `models` controller which is where you create the new @model object

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @model = Model.new
end
```

and you make the form_for look like...

```
<%= form_for [@project, @model] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. So where can I learn more about this? I'm having similar problems trying to get a link to `models#index` -- if I do `link_to(model.name, [project, model])` it routes to `project_model` instead of `project_models`. And there will be a lot more of these before I finish, so rather than asking each time, I need some documentation I understand!

Comment: There's lots available on nested resources.  The Ryan Bates RailsCast is a bit outdated, but you could try this document... https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080

The rule of thumb is... if a specific model doesn't exist (like "index" or "new" or any collection action) you just refer to the parent... so index is project_models_path(@project)... if you're referencing a specific model, that model has an :id so you don't need nesting to identify the record context, you can do model_path(@model) for a show action.

Comment: Incidentally, regarding your comment, a link to `models#index` wouldn't reference a specific model as in `model.name`, models#index implies a list of models.

Comment: Yes, it's a list of models I wanted. So including a `model` instance made it think I wanted a particular model? That makes sense.

I have trouble accessing webcasts at work (unless I remember to bring headphones in), but I'll certainly work through the gist.github article. Thanks.